# How do I filter sanitize input in PHP?

Tags: php, session, post

I have some code below which I'm trying to filter sanitize a form but it requires to be in a $_SESSION because I need my items from another page to be added onto this page and displayed as a cart list. Anyway for now I'm having trouble getting my code to filter anything. It doesn't work but not sure what I've done wrong here?[CODE][1]

If  $_POST  data is valid,  the customer details must be added to a $_SESSION  and the user be forwarded to a new script called  receipt.php

```
  <?php

  session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

    $name =    filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email =   filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone =   filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
    $address = filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, 'address', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



}
?>
```

---

So at this point I need to submit the form to itself for testing purposes, now heres my code at this current time:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_POST['add']) === false ) {

$name =    filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email =   filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone =   filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
$address = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


}
?>
<form method="post" action="cart.php" id="form1">

    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br><br>
    <label for="tel">Phone:</label><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone">
    <br><br>
    <label for="textarea">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="textarea" name="address">
    <br>

    <div id="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember">
    </div> 

    <div id="label1">
        <label for="checkbox">Remember Me</label>       
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit">   

</form>
```

I also have a debug module on the page and now its in the $_POST array instead go GET which is good but when I put html entities inside the name input field they still aren't being sanitised/removed.

Debug Module:

```
$_POST contains:
Array
(
[name] => Frost
[email] => 
[phone] => 
[address] => 
)
```

*Frost shows in bold when I add the BOLD html tag into its input field but the whole point of this is to stop that from happening.

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error? Is it not having the expected result? Please provide more details.

Comment: Add all code to your question as _text_, and _not_ as an image.

Comment: there is no constant `INPUT_SESSION`. use `INPUT_POST` f.e. or [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: If you [read the manual about about filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), you'll see how you actually use that function. Alternatively, use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: Sorry, So I need to read in from POST, apply filter, write out to SESSION, thats what Im having trouble with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INPUT_SESSION` does not exist - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

In any case, since you are looking to store validated POST data to a session the code you wrote wouldn't work even if there was an `INPUT_SESSION`.

Instead use something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)  
    && ($name    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    && ($email   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
    && ($phone   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone", FILTER_SANITIZE_INT))
    && ($address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "address", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    ) {
        $_SESSION['foobar'] = [
            'name'    => $name,
            'email'   => $email,
            'phone'   => $phone,
            'address' => $address,
        ];
}
```

This way you check that POST data has been submitted as well as assertaining the desired validity before assigning it to your session as array.

Note that assigning values inside an `if` condition is frowned upon, this is merely to demonstrate the type of approach required, ie, check for and validate POST before assigning it to session.